# Spawn Overlap within Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, overlap, skspritenode

I am making a game using `SpriteKit`, and I have two `SKSpriteNode`s that are being spawned in using a `gameTimer` for each `SKSpriteNode`.

Is there a way to prevent the nodes from spawning on top of each other when using timers in order to spawn them onto the screen? Here's my code if needed. `addObstacle` and `updateTimer` are the functions that actually spawn the nodes.

```
//adds new obstacles every obstacleInterval seconds
gameTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: TimeInterval(obstacleInterval), target: self, selector: #selector(addObstacle), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

//adds new enemies every enemyInterval seconds
gameTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: TimeInterval(enemyInterval), target: self, selector: #selector(updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Comment: Do not understand what you are going for here, but 1) do not use Timer, and 2) just check at the time of spawn if an obstacle exists at the location you plan on spawning